# Waiting synhronization of localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

There is synchronization issue between localstorage and server.

Countries,Cities,Users are synchronized with server seperately.(Seperate ajax calls)

The problem is other Javascript codes (Kncokout Bindings and etc.) must wait synchronization process. Or better a javascript function have to wait another one.

How can I implement it?

PS: I'm using jquery,amplifyjs (for localstorage interaction),knockoutjs libraries.
PS2: I need cross browser solution :)

**EDİT**
Summary:

I have 3 Javascript functions. All of them makes asynchronous ajax call with callback.
These functions could work as parallel.(Don't have to wait each others)

But the code have to work after these 3 functions.(Because these functions are synchronizing local storage and the code uses localstorage)

Comment: Please show some code of what you have already tried. It's a bit unclear what you're asking as the post is now. Usually you use the ajax callback mechanism to continue after an ajax-operation is completed. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I've added summary info.

Comment: Having one ajaxCall MIGHT boost performences depending on what exactly each do... If all 3 are fused to one, it'd also be easier to launch the app scripts afterwards.

Comment: Yes, but one ajax call means more maintanence cost :) Because every object (City,Country..) has own version key.

Comment: @ozz could you not create a separate service that performs the three services? sure, it's one more page to maintain, but at least you're still keeping the others separate. And it can positively impact client-side performance while reducing client-side code/maintenance. You could even break it down to a level where you have a service whos purpose is to call n other services and return the data from each in an array.

Comment: The detail:) This is sync issue, if I create new City, CitySync will sync only cities. But if I make one single call for all of them, all Countries,Cities,Users are sent to client (network overhead) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use deferred objects and `$.when`, that's one of it's primary uses.

```
$.when($.ajax(...),$.ajax(...),$.ajax(...)).done(function(){
    // all three are done
});
```

Comment: I need to implement them with javascript classes,(I'm using TypeScript) Could you send any implemantation detail for deferred objects? Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com has a section for deferred objects, otherwise you could go to the src on github, it's neatly organized in a file called deferred.js

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can implement this, provided that you are initiating the ajax calls at the same time. A simple count-track can solve it -

```
var countCalls;
```

Then in your ajax related code:

```
function initAjaxCalls() {

    countCalls = 0; //(re)set counter

    startAjax1(commonCallback); //pseudo call, use commomCallback as callback
    startAjax2(commonCallback);
    startAjax3(commonCallback);

}
```

On the callback we keep track of number of calls:

```
function commonCallback(e) {

    countCalls++;

    /// when we have reached the max count, perform the sync. step
    if (countCalls === 3) performSyncStorage();
}
```

This will wait until the longest lasting operation has finished. This is necessary if you want to sort of convert an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.

Comment: Thanks. I will set as accepted answer if there is not better option in 2 hours. Best regards.